# rc battery and connector issues when used in other applications

Tags: power-supply, batteries, battery-charging, robotics

I purchased this [battery](https://www.maplin.co.uk/p/96-v-2000-mah-battery-pack-for-radio-controlled-toys-n49gf) for my robotics project and this [charger](https://www.maplin.co.uk/p/prophet-sport-35w-ac-nimh-battery-charger-a18uj) along with it. Since the regular use for these types of batteries is for rc cars they have very specific connectors and so i am unable to connect the battery and charger together because of the connectors and i am also unable to unable to connect the battery into a bread board for the robot. Ive done a bit of research and the batttery has a tamiya connector and the charger has a ec3 connector.

Is there a way to join the battery to jumper cables to plug into the robot or special connector that does this and what would I have to do in order to connect the battery to the charger?
I was thinking about cutting off the connectors and using jumper cables to join the cables. Would this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the connectors are wrong, there's nothing to stop you cutting them off and replacing them with whatever connectors suit your purpose.  Just make sure you get the polarity (+ and -) the right way round, or bad things are likely to happen.

Comment: Can i cut the connectors off both the battery and charger and join the bare wires with jumper cables?

Comment: @undertakersaab Yes - just don't let the wires short together.